# Form validation in bootstrap submit button is not enabled

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, formvalidation-plugin

Save button is not enabled to submit the form even though the validations are correct.

```html
<form id="userForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal"
      action="updatePetitionerView.do" style="display: none;">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Passport Number</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <input type="text" name="passport" size="9" maxlength="10"
             class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Passport Number"
             data-toggle="tooltip" autocomplete="off"
             data-placement="top" id="passport"
             title="Enter Passport Number" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">PAN Number</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">

      <input type="text" name="pan" size="10" maxlength="10"
             class="form-control" placeholder="Enter PAN Number"
             data-toggle="tooltip" autocomplete="off"
             data-placement="top" id="pan" title="Enter PAN Number" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">FAX Number</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <input type="text" name="fax" size="10" maxlength="15"
             class="form-control" placeholder="Enter FAX Number"
             data-toggle="tooltip" autocomplete="off"
             data-placement="top" id="fax" title="Enter FAX Number" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Occupation</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <input type="text" name="occupation" size="14" maxlength="30"
             class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Occupation"
             data-toggle="tooltip" autocomplete="off"
             data-placement="top" id="occupation"
             title="Enter Occupation" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Country</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <input type="text" name="country" size="14"
             class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Country"
             data-toggle="tooltip" autocomplete="off"
             data-placement="top" id="country" title="Enter Country" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Nationality</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <input type="text" name="nationality" size="14"
             class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Nationality"
             data-toggle="tooltip" autocomplete="off"
             data-placement="top" id="nationality"
             title="Enter Nationality" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Alternate Phone
      Number</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <input type="text" name="phone" size="10" maxlength="10"
             class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Phone Number"
             data-toggle="tooltip" autocomplete="off"
             data-placement="top" id="phone" title="Enter Phone Number" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Alternate
      Address</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="2"
                placeholder="Enter Alternate Address"
                name="alternateaddress" data-placement="top"
                id="alternateaddress"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="ptyno" id="ptyno" /> <input
                                                         type="hidden" name="type" id="type" />
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
              data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="submit" id="fmodel" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

```js
var $frm = $('#userForm');
$frm
.formValidation({
  framework : 'bootstrap',
  icon : {
    valid : 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
    invalid : 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
    validating : 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
  },
  fields : {
    complaint : {
      row : '.col-xs-3',
      validators : {
        notEmpty : {
          message : 'The Complaint name is required'
        },
        stringLength : {
          min : 3,
          max : 25,
          message : 'The Complaint Name must be more than 3 and less than 25 characters long'
        },
        regexp : {
          regexp : /^[a-zA-Z]+$/,
          message : 'The Complaint Name can only consist of alphabetical'
        }
      }
    },
    address : {
      row : '.col-xs-3',
      validators : {
        notEmpty : {
          message : 'The Address is required'
        },
        regexp : {
          regexp : /^[a-zA-Z\s\.0-9#-_/]+$/,
          message : 'The Address can only consist of a-zA-Z\.0-9#-_/'
        }
      }
    },
    advocateName : {
      row : '.col-xs-3',
      validators : {
        notEmpty : {
          message : 'The Advocate name is required'
        },
        stringLength : {
          min : 3,
          max : 25,
          message : 'The Advocate Name must be more than 3 and less than 25 characters long'
        },
        regexp : {
          regexp : /^[a-zA-Z]+$/,
          message : 'The Advocate Name can only consist of alphabetical'
        }
      }
    },
    passport : {
      row : '.col-xs-3',
      validators : {
        notEmpty : {
          message : 'The Passport is required'
        },
        regexp : {
          regexp : /[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{7}/,
          message : 'The Passport can only consist of Alphabetical & Numeric'
        }
      }
    },

    age : {
      row : '.col-xs-3',
      validators : {
        notEmpty : {
          message : 'The age is required'
        },
        stringLength : {
          min : 1,
          max : 3,
          message : 'The age must be more than 1 and less than 3 characters long'
        },
        regexp : {
          regexp : /^[0-9]+$/,
          message : 'The first can only consist of alphabetical'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you create a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [bin](http://jsbin.com/) to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Not trying to skip the point, but those validations should be done server side, anyone can disable their browser JS and screw with your database.
But if you must, put your code on Codepen for us.

Comment: @MarcelCaferati - _"those validations should be done server side"_  - Yes, you must have server-side validation. But there's no reason why they shouldn't be available on client-side as well. I always use both.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $frm = $('#userForm');
$frm
.formValidation({
  framework : 'bootstrap',
  icon : {
    valid : 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
    invalid : 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
    validating : 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
  },
  fields : {
    complaint : {
      row : '.col-xs-3',
      validators : {
        notEmpty : {
          message : 'The Complaint name is required'
        },
        stringLength : {
          min : 3,
          max : 25,
          message : 'The Complaint Name must be more than 3 and less than 25 characters long'
        },
        regexp : {
          regexp : /^[a-zA-Z]+$/,
          message : 'The Complaint Name can only consist of alphabetical'
        }
      }
    },
    address : {
      row : '.col-xs-3',
      validators : {
        notEmpty : {
          message : 'The Address is required'
        },
        regexp : {
          regexp : /^[a-zA-Z\s\.0-9#-_/]+$/,
          message : 'The Address can only consist of a-zA-Z\.0-9#-_/'
        }
      }
    },
    advocateName : {
      row : '.col-xs-3',
      validators : {
        notEmpty : {
          message : 'The Advocate name is required'
        },
        stringLength : {
          min : 3,
          max : 25,
          message : 'The Advocate Name must be more than 3 and less than 25 characters long'
        },
        regexp : {
          regexp : /^[a-zA-Z]+$/,
          message : 'The Advocate Name can only consist of alphabetical'
        }
      }
    },
    passport : {
      row : '.col-xs-3',
      validators : {
        notEmpty : {
          message : 'The Passport is required'
        },
        regexp : {
          regexp : /[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{7}/,
          message : 'The Passport can only consist of Alphabetical & Numeric'
        }
      }
    },

    age : {
      row : '.col-xs-3',
      validators : {
        notEmpty : {
          message : 'The age is required'
        },
        stringLength : {
          min : 1,
          max : 3,
          message : 'The age must be more than 1 and less than 3 characters long'
        },
        regexp : {
          regexp : /^[0-9]+$/,
          message : 'The first can only consist of alphabetical'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/js/framework/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/bootbox/4.2.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<form id="userForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal"
      action="updatePetitionerView.do" style="display: none;">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Passport Number</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <input type="text" name="passport" size="9" maxlength="10"
             class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Passport Number"
             data-toggle="tooltip" autocomplete="off"
             data-placement="top" id="passport"
             title="Enter Passport Number" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">PAN Number</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">

      <input type="text" name="pan" size="10" maxlength="10"
             class="form-control" placeholder="Enter PAN Number"
             data-toggle="tooltip" autocomplete="off"
             data-placement="top" id="pan" title="Enter PAN Number" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">FAX Number</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <input type="text" name="fax" size="10" maxlength="15"
             class="form-control" placeholder="Enter FAX Number"
             data-toggle="tooltip" autocomplete="off"
             data-placement="top" id="fax" title="Enter FAX Number" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Occupation</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <input type="text" name="occupation" size="14" maxlength="30"
             class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Occupation"
             data-toggle="tooltip" autocomplete="off"
             data-placement="top" id="occupation"
             title="Enter Occupation" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Country</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <input type="text" name="country" size="14"
             class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Country"
             data-toggle="tooltip" autocomplete="off"
             data-placement="top" id="country" title="Enter Country" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Nationality</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <input type="text" name="nationality" size="14"
             class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Nationality"
             data-toggle="tooltip" autocomplete="off"
             data-placement="top" id="nationality"
             title="Enter Nationality" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Alternate Phone
      Number</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <input type="text" name="phone" size="10" maxlength="10"
             class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Phone Number"
             data-toggle="tooltip" autocomplete="off"
             data-placement="top" id="phone" title="Enter Phone Number" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Alternate
      Address</label>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="2"
                placeholder="Enter Alternate Address"
                name="alternateaddress" data-placement="top"
                id="alternateaddress"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="ptyno" id="ptyno" /> <input
                                                         type="hidden" name="type" id="type" />
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
              data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="submit" id="fmodel" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```